# Process of deriving TVC(transversality conditon)

Tags: macroeconomics

In Kruger's note, the process of deriving TVC is expressed as:
$0=lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^t U'(f(k_t)-k_{t+1})k_{t+1}=lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^{t-1} U'(f(k_{t-1})-k_{t})k_{t}
=lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^{t-1}\beta U'(f(k_{t})-k_{t+1})f'(k_t)k_{t}=lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^{t} U'(f(k_{t})-k_{t+1})f'(k_t)k_{t}$
The third equation is from Euler equation.
But how can I derive from first the second equation?
$lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^t U'(f(k_t)-k_{t+1})k_{t+1}=lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \beta^{t-1} U'(f(k_{t-1})-k_{t})k_{t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can I derive from first the second equation? $lim_{t
>  \rightarrow \infty} \beta^t U'(f(k_t)-k_{t+1})k_{t+1}=lim_{t
>  \rightarrow \infty} \beta^{t-1} U'(f(k_{t-1})-k_{t})k_{t}$

You can notice that the second side of the equation is just a relabeling of the first side, where  $t$ is replaced by  $t-1$, so that they actually are the same equation.

In the second side of the equation we have $lim_{t
 \rightarrow \infty}$, even if, re-labeling, one could think that it should be   $lim_{(t-1)
 \rightarrow \infty}$.  But it is the same, as $(t-1) \rightarrow \infty \Leftrightarrow t \rightarrow \infty$ ($-1$ is a fixed number, so $t$ must go to infinity).